# Upon Logout in Play2 getting TimeoutException in Tomcat 8.5.x and higher

Tags: playframework-2.0, tomcat8

I am new to Play Framework and Tomcat. In my application when redirecting I receive "TimeoutException". It gets stuck at line redirect("signout.html") and throws the error.

This happens only in Tomcat 8.5.23 and higher (Tried in Tomcat 9.0.2). It works fine in Tomcat 8.0.32. Please advise.

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: This request was timed out after 300000 ms
    play.core.server.servlet25.Play2Servlet25RequestHandler.onFinishService(RequestHandler.scala:36)
    play.core.server.servlet.Play2GenericServletRequestHandler.apply(RequestHandler.scala:371)
    play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$$anonfun$handleRequest$2.apply(Play2Server.scala:64)
    play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$$anonfun$handleRequest$2.apply(Play2Server.scala:64)
    scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$.handleRequest(Play2Server.scala:64)
    play.core.server.servlet.GenericPlay2Servlet.service(Play2CommonServlet.scala:36)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix this issue by upgrading Play framework servlet version from 2.5 to 3.1.